# Correct way of using getopts

Tags: shell, getopts

Executing following script gives error for *mkdir* command

```
PATH=/root
while getopts "r" name;
do
    case $name in
        r)
            PATH=/home
            ;;
        *)
            echo "Usage: $0 -r"
            ;;
    esac
done

echo $PATH
mkdir new
```

error:

```
./test.sh: line 15: mkdir: command not found
```

What's wrong in this script ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem doesn't really have anything to do with `getopts`.

The problem is the first line:

```
PATH=/root
```

or, if it's executed, this line:

```
PATH=/home
```

This sets the search path for commands to *just* the `/root` or `/home` directory. (Typically neither of those directories contains any commands).

Setting `$PATH` throws away the previous value. `mkdir` is probably in `/bin`, but since `/bin` is no longer in `$PATH`, the shell can't find it.

You don't get an error on the `getopts` command because it's built into the shell you're using.

If you want to add `/root` to your `$PATH`, use:

```
PATH="/root:$PATH"
```

or

```
PATH="$PATH:/root"
```

But nothing in your script appears to depend on having `/root` in your `$PATH`. Why are you doing `PATH=/root` in the first place? If you're trying to set your current working directory to `/root` or `/home`, you want the `chdir` command.